# cannot find symbol symbol: class WindowSignIn location: package com.glim.antony

Tags: java, swing

Подскажите в чем может быть причина. Иногда IntellijIDEa выполняет программу без проблем, иногда выдает такую вот ошибку. Как исправить это?

Из класса Main я вызываю другой класс прописанный отдельно но в той же директории. Из второго класса вызываю еще класс. (Одно окно при нажатии на кнопку открывает другое окно).

Кто сталкивался, подскажите

Один класс

```
package com.glim.antony;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        WindowSignIn windowSignIn = new WindowSignIn();
        windowSignIn.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Второй класс:

```
package com.glim.antony;

public class WindowSignIn extends JFrame
{
    JTextField loginField;
    JPasswordField passwordField;

    WindowSignIn()
    {
        super("Вход в систему");    // arrTextOfProgram[0];
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        .
        .
        .
        setResizable(false); //не изменяемый размер окна
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Размещение по центру экрана
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);   // Окно всегда поверх остальных окон;
    }
}
```

Comment: красным идея ничего не выделяет, к примеру, требуя импорты проставить?

Comment: Ничего не подчеркивает, ничего не прочит И иногда выполняется, а иногда нет.

Comment: Работаю я с разных компов. Проект на гугл диске. Дома запускается, на работе - нет. Раньше такого не было. Обе системы 64. Обе винды. Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Для устранения ошибки при работе над проектом с разных ПК через Google диск, необходимо перед запуском программы перестроить проект.

Меню Build --> Rebuild Project

Тогда все работает.